# Return exclusive elements from two lists that comes more than twice using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
    int[] List1 = { 10, 10029, 30, 30, 10030 };
    int[] List2 = { 14,22,23,24,25,26,2728,29,10029,10030 };
```

and the following statement,

```
var NewList = List1.Except(List2);
```

returns

```
10
30
```

but I want the output to include the exclusive elements that have been duplicated. So,

```
10 
30
30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ with the semantics you're looking for:

```cs
var newList = List1.Where(x => !List2.Contains(x));
```

Note that this is quadratic in the size of the lists. If the lists are large then this might take a long time. To alleviate that, you can turn the other list to a set first, for fast lookup:

```cs
var list2AsSet = List2.ToHashSet();
var newList = List1.Where(x => !list2AsSet.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Contains` method to determine if the element exist in the second list

```
int[] List1 = { 10, 10029, 30, 30, 10030 };
int[] List2 = { 14,22,23,24,25,26,2728,29,10029,10030 };
var exclusive = List1.Where(x => !List2.Contains(x));
            
foreach (var el in exclusive){
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

More about `Contains` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0